# How to visualize data to make maxima and minima clear?

Tags: data-visualization, data-transformation

I have a tuple that looks like this when I plot the graph:
[image: the tuple itself]
But the minima are not quite clear. So I tried to use logarithmic scale and visualise the log of the tuple instead of the tuple itself.
[image: log of the tuple]
But now, the maxima are not clear. Eventually I tried -1/log(x). This way both maxima and minima look clear.
[image: -1/log]
But I wonder if this is the neatest way to scale that type of data. Would you recommend any other scaling options?

Comment: Is this a time series? Please tell us what this data represents!

Comment: no, this is a "consonance" (harmoniousness of two musical tones) plot within a span of one octave (the range between two tones with frequency ratio of 2) the x axis is the 12 tones within the octave, the y axis is the harmoniousness of those 12 tones with the first note.

Comment: Please add that explanation as an edit to the post! It might help somebody to give an informed answer.-

Comment: Try cube root scale. Logarithmic scale is clearly too strong in that extreme minima pop out as outliers. I wish I understood the science here to be less _ad hoc_.